# Brightness control not working on laptop ubuntu16.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, screen, brightness, backlight

I'm stuck with my brightness control options.
I have two keys with brightness control (fn + up or down arrow) and they don't work at all. I am on a MSI gl72 6qf, with a nvidia 960M.

I edited the /etc/default/grub which now looks like this :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

(i tried acpi_osi=linux; acpi_backlight=vendor ; video.use_native_backlight=1 and it did nothing)

And I still can't change my brightess via my hotkeys.
I tried xbacklight who answers me : "No outputs have backlight property".

brightness-controller and brightness-indicator don't work either.

My screen is "undetected" according to system settings.

When I tried acpi_listen, my hotkeys are well recognized so it doesn't come from here.

I'm on the nvidia driver 370.28

EDIT : /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

```
# This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd

# replaced by e100
blacklist eepro100

# replaced by tulip
blacklist de4x5

# causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth1394

# snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
# hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810)
blacklist snd_intel8x0m

# Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device)
blacklist snd_aw2

# causes failure to suspend on HP compaq nc6000 (Ubuntu: #10306)
blacklist i2c_i801

# replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54

# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx

# most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565)
blacklist garmin_gps

# replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721)
blacklist asus_acpi


# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes

# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)

blacklist snd_pcsp


# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a

# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)

blacklist pcspkr


# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture

# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver

# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac
#blacklist acpi_video0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52300/discussion-on-question-by-nanakix-brightness-control-not-working-on-laptop-ubunt).

Comment: I tried nvidia-switch and it tells me that /etc/modprobe.d is not a file and that there's no alternatives to x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my problem :

I followed the instructions on this page I did not found during my researches :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

So, assuming the situation described above,  go into the "additional drivers" section of ubuntu, I switched to 367.57 driver, and in the /etc/default/grub , 
change this line :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to this :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash modeset=nouveau"
```